# Package that visualizes spacing?

Tags: spacing, packages

Is there a package that visualizes and label all the spacings in a document, similar to what this diagram shows (except it would label exactly how many pts each variable is)?

[image: spacing visualized]

Comment: Have a look at the [`layouts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package

Comment: @siracusa Is that something I can include in an already-existing document and it'll superimpose boxes and labels? How do I use it? Could you please provide an answer showing how to use it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 7 of the [`layouts` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) explains the provided commands related to list designs. There are two main macros: `\listdiagram` and `\listdesign`, where the latter shows the current values for all list parameters but doesn't draw the full list layout diagram as provided by the former macro.

By redefining an internal macro we can still define a new command that provides both diagram and values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listvaluesdiagram{%
    \begingroup
    \def\testprintparameters{\l@ytempiftrue}%
    \drawlist
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listvaluesdiagram
\end{document}
```

[image]